# RcppArmadillo compilation error

Tags: r, rcpp

I am running R in redhat 5.9 (gcc version 4.2)  and get the following compiliation error messege :

---

g++ -I/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/include -I/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/library/Rcpp/include -I/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/library/RcppArmadillo/include  -I. -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
In file included from ../inst/include/armadillo:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:37,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppArmadillo.h:30,
                 from RcppArmadillo.cpp:22:
../inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:119:6: error: #error "*** Need a newer compiler ***"
/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function âvoid Rcpp::Date::update_tm()â:
/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to âtime_tâ from âdoubleâ
/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function âRcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)â:
/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to âtime_tâ from âdoubleâ
ia64make: *** [RcppArmadillo.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package âRcppArmadilloâ
* removing â/home/gn31131/R_downloads/R_inst/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadilloâ

---

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are stuck with gcc/g++ 4.2, you will indeed either need to upgrade the compiler, or need to downgrade RcppArmadillo to an older version.  Current versions test via

```
#if (ARMA_GCC_VERSION < 40200) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
  #error "*** Need a newer compiler ***"
#endif
```

and this bites on your system.

You can access all released versions via [CRAN's Archive page for the package](http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/) and you may just have to try something older.

Or upgrade your OS (version).  Newer RHEL/CentOS have newer compilers, but I'd actually recommend Ubuntu's LTS versions.